# A Button changing a CSS Element

Tags: javascript, css

So I have this button:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

and I have this CSS attribute:

```
.rouletteWheelGradient{
margin-top: 52;
}
```

Is that possible to change the `52px` to `62px` when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 2):

Not with raw CSS, but this is certainly possible with JavaScript. First, we need to add a click function to the HTML to trigger the JavaScript:

```
<button type="button" class="close" onclick="move()" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Then we need to build a function that moves `.rouletteWheelGradient`:

```
function move() {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("rouletteWheelGradient").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("rouletteWheelGradient")[i].style.marginTop = "62px";
  }
}
```

Note the `px` at the end of the function, which represents pixels. You need to specify a unit of measurement for your selector, and you're missing this in your CSS.

**Here's a working example**:

```js
function move() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("rouletteWheelGradient").length; i++) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("rouletteWheelGradient")[i].style.marginTop = "62px"
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="close" onclick="move()" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<div id="1" class="rouletteWheelGradient">One</div>
<div id="2" class="rouletteWheelGradient">Two</div>
<div id="3" class="rouletteWheelGradient">Three</div>
```

The above sample gives **every** element with class `rouletteWheelGradient` a top margin of 62px when the button is clicked.

I've also created a JSFiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/qz6x8jzz/1/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'd recommend doing this by id rather than classname since you might later apply that class to multiple objects.

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first, though by the name `gradient`, I'm assuming there could be multiple classes with the same name. I'd assume that they would all want to be changed at once in a roulette wheel's offset. You can always target an individual element with `document.getElementsByClassName('.rouletteWheelGradient')[x]` anyway, where `x` is the nth element with that class :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a little JQuery:

```
$('button.close').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.rouletteWheelGradient').css({'margin-top':'62px'});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wrunnvqa/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with some regular JavaScript.

Just add an `id` and `onclick` attribute to your button tag like so

`<button id="btn" onclick="change()" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>`

then somewhere on the page you add a function inside a script tag

`<script>`
    `function change(){
        document.getElementById("btn").style.marginTop= '62px';
    }`
`</script>`